# Unable to use sticky header in primeng table

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng-datatable

I am trying to use sticky header with p-table. However I'm not able to do so. I am using the css that's been mentioned in their documentation. I'm using primeng 7. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my template:

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" #dt [value]="students" [autoLayout]="true" [paginator]="true" [rows]="100" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[100,200,500]" >
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
                {{col.header}}
                <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
            {{rowData[col.field]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>

</p-table>
```

My Css:

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-table .ui-table-thead > tr > th {
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            position: sticky;
            top: 69px;
            box-shadow: 1px 3px 6px 0 rgba(32,33,36,0.10);
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 64em) {
            :host ::ng-deep .ui-table .ui-table-thead > tr > th {
                top: 99px;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste Your CSS in Your Table component not Global Component :

```
   :host ::ng-deep .ui-table .ui-table-thead > tr > th {
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            position: sticky;
            top: 69px;
            box-shadow: 1px 3px 6px 0 rgba(32,33,36,0.10);
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 64em) {
            :host ::ng-deep .ui-table .ui-table-thead > tr > th {
                top: 99px;
            }
        }
```

Comment: this css is added to css file that is referred by the component.

Comment: so can you put this css in Style.css file and also check primeng  css file is imported correctly